# I don't how to fix Typescript Angular compile error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the result from api request but have compiler error and i don't know how to fix it.

The error is:

> Error: src/app/pages/home/home.component.ts:59:22 - error TS2339: Property 'filterRooms' does not exist on type 'RoomService'.

room.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Room } from '../interfaces/room';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoomService {

  private serviceUrl = environment.baseServiceUrl + 'room/';
  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  filterRooms(parameters: any=null, filters: any=null): Observable<any> {
    ...
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(requestUrl, { params: httpParams, headers: httpHeaders })
      .pipe(
        tap(res => {
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<Room[]>('Room filterRooms', []))
    );
  }
}
```

home.component.ts:

```
import { Room } from '../../interfaces/room';
import { RoomService } from '../../services/room.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  private rooms: Room[] = [];
  constructor(
    private roomService: RoomService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filterRooms();
  }

  filterRooms(): any {
    this.roomService.filterRooms(parameters)
    .subscribe(rooms => {
      this.rooms = <Room[]> rooms.results;
    });
  }
}
```

Anybody could help me please ?

Comment: Can you share the whole service file ? I think you either have bad indent or you didn't saved your file.

Comment: You've cut out so much context that it is impossible to determine what the issue is. The compiler error *should* be clear: somewhere you have a `RoomService` typed object, but at that point, `RoomService` does not seem to have a `filterRooms` on it.

Comment: Please show the home component, where the error is

Comment: Sorry, this component is home component

Comment: I think the problem is due to filterRooms has 2 parameters (parameters, filters) instead one parameter.

Comment: @JoseVicente try without parameters and the error persist.

Comment: Where does `parameters` come from in `this.roomService.filterRooms(parameters)`? If possible, provide a [mre].